# Why Does <th> Not Span 100% Width of the Row? HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've created a basic HTML table yet I can't seem to get the top `<th>` element to span 100% width of it's parent `<tr>` element (and ultimately the `<table>` element).

```css
.my-card-table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #D9D7D6;
  table-layout: fixed!important;
}

.table-top-heading {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-card-table-heading {
  background-color: #E9E9E9!important;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.my-card-table-heading-inner {
  background-color: #E9E9E9!important;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 30px
}

.my-card-table-row-grey {
  background-color: #F2F3F3!important;
  padding: 10px!important;
}

.my-card-table-row-white {
  background-color: #ffffff!important;
  padding: 10px!important;
}

..my-table-td {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.my-card-link {
  color: #0e5b8b;
}

.my-card-link:hover {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
  color: #0e5b8b;
}

.my-card-link-2 {
  color: #212529;
}
```

```html
<table class="my-card-table">
  <tr class="table-top-heading">
    <th class="table-top-heading-header">HelloWorld</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-card-table-heading">
    <th class="my-card-table-heading-inner">Teachers</th>
    <th class="my-card-table-heading-inner">School</th>
    <th class="my-card-table-heading-inner">Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
    <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 1</a></td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Long Grove</td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Logged In</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-card-table-row-white">
    <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 2</a></td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Long Grove</td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Logged In</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
    <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 3</a></td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Lincolnshire</td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Logged In</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-card-table-row-white">
    <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 4</a></td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Buffalo Grove</td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Logged In</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
    <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 5</a></td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Kenilworth</td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Not Logged In</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-card-table-row-white">
    <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 6</a></td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Schaumburg</td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Not Logged In</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
    <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 7</a></td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Schaumburg</td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Not Logged In</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So when you run that code snippet ^ what I want to see is 'helloWorld' centered above the 'Teachers, School, Status' row. I'm not sure why it only seems to be expanding a quarter of the table width - does it have to do with the `table-layout: fixed` style that I've set on the `<table>` element?

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/cwhzb35n/7/)

Comment: this will be usefull to you : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics to understand how a table works and is to be build. check on the colspan attribute for a quick hint.

Comment: Have you not set the width of the header or am I missing something?

Comment: @rguttersohn I was missing that style in the CSS but please see this updated Fiddle to see that adding width (and colspan) to the th and tr have not had any effect: http://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/cwhzb35n/12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1.) You need to add `colspan="3"` as an attribute to that `th`to make it span all three columns of that table.

2.) You *should not* use `display: block` for a table element, regardless if that's `td`, `th`, `tr` or whatever. The display setting of the `th` by default is `table-cell`- just leave that as it is, otherwise the table won't be a "real table" in the end (i.e. the cells loose their automatic way of aligning and adjusting themselves).

```css
.my-card-table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #D9D7D6;
  table-layout: fixed!important;
}

.table-top-heading {
  text-align: center;
}

.my-card-table-heading {
  background-color: #E9E9E9!important;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.my-card-table-heading-inner {
  background-color: #E9E9E9!important;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 30px
}

.my-card-table-row-grey {
  background-color: #F2F3F3!important;
  padding: 10px!important;
}

.my-card-table-row-white {
  background-color: #ffffff!important;
  padding: 10px!important;
}

..my-table-td {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.my-card-link {
  color: #0e5b8b;
}

.my-card-link:hover {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
  color: #0e5b8b;
}

.my-card-link-2 {
  color: #212529;
}
```

```html
<table class="my-card-table">
  <tr class="table-top-heading">
    <th class="table-top-heading-header" colspan="3">HelloWorld</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-card-table-heading">
    <th class="my-card-table-heading-inner">Teachers</th>
    <th class="my-card-table-heading-inner">School</th>
    <th class="my-card-table-heading-inner">Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
    <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 1</a></td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Long Grove</td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Logged In</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-card-table-row-white">
    <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 2</a></td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Long Grove</td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Logged In</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
    <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 3</a></td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Lincolnshire</td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Logged In</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-card-table-row-white">
    <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 4</a></td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Buffalo Grove</td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Logged In</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
    <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 5</a></td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Kenilworth</td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Not Logged In</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-card-table-row-white">
    <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 6</a></td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Schaumburg</td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Not Logged In</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
    <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 7</a></td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Schaumburg</td>
    <td class="my-table-td">Not Logged In</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's unbelievable but when I copy and paste your code into JSFiddle it's still giving me the same result: http://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/76amLkw4/3/. `display: block` has been removed and `colspan="3"` has been added. **Edit** However, it's working on my live server so maybe the issue is with JSFiddle in that case. Thank you.

Comment: @HappyHands31 It is caused by settings in JS fiddle. If you click on the down arrow beside the CSS text at the top of the CSS section you will see a Option that is turned on called "Normalized CSS'. Turn that off and it behaves the way you want it to when you rerun your sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your ".my-card-table" and ".table-top-heading" to {display:flex}, and your ".table-top-heading-header" to {width:100%; text-align: center}.

You also had an extra (.) on your (my-table-td ) class.

Here's a working solution ;)

```css
.my-card-table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #D9D7D6;
    display: flex;
}

.table-top-heading {
  width: 100%;  
  display: flex;
}

.table-top-heading-header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-card-table-heading {
    background-color: #E9E9E9!important;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.my-card-table-heading-inner {
    background-color: #E9E9E9!important;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 30px
}

.my-card-table-row-grey {
    background-color: #F2F3F3!important;
    padding: 10px!important;
}

.my-card-table-row-white {
    background-color: #ffffff!important;
    padding: 10px!important;
}

.my-table-td {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.my-card-link {
    color: #0e5b8b;
}

.my-card-link:hover {
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
    color: #0e5b8b;
}

.my-card-link-2 {
    color: #212529;
}
```

```html
<table class="my-card-table">
                    <tr class="table-top-heading">
                      <th class="table-top-heading-header">HelloWorld</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="my-card-table-heading">
                      <th class="my-card-table-heading-inner">Teachers</th>
                      <th class="my-card-table-heading-inner">School</th>
                      <th class="my-card-table-heading-inner">Status</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
                      <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 1</a></td>
                      <td class="my-table-td">Long Grove</td>
                      <td class="my-table-td">Logged In</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="my-card-table-row-white">
                      <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 2</a></td>
                      <td class="my-table-td">Long Grove</td>
                      <td class="my-table-td">Logged In</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
                      <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 3</a></td>
                      <td class="my-table-td">Lincolnshire</td>
                      <td class="my-table-td">Logged In</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="my-card-table-row-white">
                      <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 4</a></td>
                      <td class="my-table-td">Buffalo Grove</td>
                      <td class="my-table-td">Logged In</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
                      <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 5</a></td>
                      <td class="my-table-td">Kenilworth</td>
                      <td class="my-table-td">Not Logged In</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="my-card-table-row-white">
                      <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 6</a></td>
                      <td class="my-table-td">Schaumburg</td>
                      <td class="my-table-td">Not Logged In</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="my-card-table-row-grey">
                      <td class="my-table-td"><a href="" onclick="return false" class="my-card-link">Teacher 7</a></td>
                      <td class="my-table-td">Schaumburg</td>
                      <td class="my-table-td">Not Logged In</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
```